# Implementing blank interface for accessing list

Tags: c#, list, interface, arraylist

Following is the code that I have been trying to deploy. As you can see I am deploying a blank interface to make a special datatype "mydatatype" for the list "mylist".
And in the output I expect the assigned values to be displayed. But I am getting gibberish data. Can somebody explain?

```
public class list
{
    interface mydatatype
    {
    }
    public class mystring : mydatatype
    {
        public string mystrings{ get; set; }

    }
    public class myint : mydatatype
    {
        public int myints{ get; set; }
    }
    public class mydouble : mydatatype
    {
        public double mydoubles{ get; set; }
    }
    public static void Main() 
    {


        List<mydatatype> mylist = new List<mydatatype>
            {
                new mystring(),
                new myint(),
                new mydouble(),
            };
        mystring ab = new mystring();
        myint mi = new myint();
        mydouble mf = new mydouble();

        ab.mystrings = "asdf";
        mi.myints = 12;
        mf.mydoubles = 12.223;

        mylist.Add(ab);
        mylist.Add(mi);
        mylist.Add(mf);
        foreach (mydatatype element in mylist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
       } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the "gibberish data" you are getting.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using nested types, and ignoring .NET naming conventions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"gibberish data" isn't a real error description...

However, what is happening here is that `Console.WriteLine(element);` is the same as `Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());`. Because you haven't overridden `ToString` in your classes, it will output the class names instead of the values. You would do that like this:

```
public class mystring : mydatatype
{
    public string mystrings{ get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return mystrings;
    }

}
public class myint : mydatatype
{
    public int myints{ get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return myints.ToString();
    }
}
public class mydouble : mydatatype
{
    public double mydoubles{ get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return mydoubles.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: By gibberish i meant my output to be as follows, and "TestApplications" is my project name ::

`TestApplications.list+mystrings
TestApplications.list+myint
TestApplications.list+mydouble
TestApplications.list+mystrings
TestApplications.list+myint
TestApplications.list+mydouble`


** The stuff to be noted is that instead of displaying the assigned values it is showing me the name of datatypes and their path..that too twice.
As by some elite advisers, i must override the ToString() method. Can anyone explain how to employ this idea ??

Comment: @deepaksahu: Please see update to my answer. BTW: You shouldn't accept an answer if it doesn't fully answer your question.

Comment: Hey Thanks Daniel Hilgarth . I just worked the same out and see the same in your update.. Now my code is working smoooth... Thanks.. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to override `ToString` in each of your classes to control the output. Currently it will just print out the classname of each object.

You are initialising the list with 3 instances of your different datatypes initially, which is why you probably see those values printed before the ones you added. I guess this is what you mean by 'gibberish data'.

Answer (score 0):

You have six elements in your array-list. Three uninitialized ones which you put into it at the time of instanciating your list and three extra initialized ones you add after that.

Displaying a each element in the list will call the `ToString()` function on each element, which by default is the type's name.

Comment: Yes you are right Jaapjan. I just removed the initialization components from the list declaration and now i am not getting those uninitialised data. And additionally i successfully implemented the ToString override and now i get what i want as my output.